# Taylor's Formula with Remainder

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to review for an exam that I have coming up and this problem is tripping me up a little bit. If I am thinking correctly, these proofs should involve some use of Taylor's Remainder Theorem and maybe even some Generalized Mean-Value Theorem as well, but I am spinning my wheels on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The problem is as follows:

Let $B$ be a neighborhood of a point $p\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $f\colon B\to \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable up to the $(n+1)$st derivative ($n\in\mathbb{N}$). Let $g\colon B\to\mathbb{R}$, $y\mapsto (y-p)^{n+1}$. Fix a point $x\in B\smallsetminus\{p\}$. Define the functions $F$ and $G$ on $B$ by
\begin{align*}
 F(t) &= f(t) +\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}(x-t)^k,\\
 G(t) &= g(t) +\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{g^{(k)}}{k!}(x-t)^k.
\end{align*} 
From Taylor's Remainder Theorem we know that
\begin{align*} 
 F'(t) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n,\qquad
 G'(t) = (n+1)(x-t)^n.
\end{align*}
(a) Show that
\begin{align*}
F(x) - F(p) = f(x) - f(p) - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}(x-p)^k.
\end{align*}
(b) Show that
\begin{align*}
G(x) - G(p) = (x-p)^{n+1}. 
\end{align*}
(c) For $c$ strictly between $x$ and $p$, show that
\begin{align*}
\frac{F'(c)}{G'(c)} = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}.
\end{align*}

Comment: (a) and (c) are just substituting the formulas given. For (a) use the expression given for $F$, for (c) use the expressions given for $F'$ and $G'$. (b) is a little more interesting.

Comment: Is it really that easy for parts (a) and (c)? Could we not use a similar approach for part (b) then as well?

Comment: I don't see it - the expression given for $G$ is more complicated than $(n-p)^{n+1}$. I suggest instead thinking about how to use the expression for the derivative $G'$ to get an expression for $G(x)-G(p)$.